# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/ws/rs/client/Client

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jax-rs

I try to use restful web services jax-rs with jsf.

My pom.xml is defined as bellow:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.yahia</groupId>
<artifactId>TestMaven</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>TestMaven Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>Prime Repo</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <!-- PrimeFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PrimeFaces theme -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JUnit testing framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.12</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring AOP dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- c3p0 dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate framework -->
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>hibernate</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>3.2.3.GA</version> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->



    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->


    <!-- JSR 311 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>TestMaven</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and i have defined those two methodes in my managedbean:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/TestMaven/rs/test");
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroy()
{
    client.close();
}
```

But when i start up my tomcat server i have got the following error:

```
GRAVE: Critical error during deployment: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/ws/rs/client/Client;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
at ..........
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/ws/rs/client/Client;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
at 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.Client
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
... 34 more
```

How can i solve this problem  ?

Answer (score 0):

If your scope is provided I would think you would be expecting that dependency to come from a server resource. If that's the way you would deploy this in the end, you could try adding that jar to your server lib.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i solve this problem ?

Here's how >>you<< can solve this problem.

1. Look at the stacktrace to find the FQN for the class that is missing.
2. Use the [findjar service](http://www.findjar.com/index.x) to identify the public JARs that include the class you need.
3. Do some simple research to figure out an appropriate version.  For example, identify and visit the corresponding developer website and see what they recommend as maven dependencies.
4. Add or modify a dependency in your POM file.
5. Repeat as required.